# Disallowing this specific useragent via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to disallow this useragent via htaccess, but exactly as it is (it is a bot faking a firefox client):

Mozilla/15.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0

but due to the amount of escape signs something seems not to work right.

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla/15\.0\ \(Windows\ NT\ 6\.1;\ rv\:17\.0\)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/17\.0 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

but it does not seem to work. any ideas what's going wrong here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/ is a special character, so put an \ also before /.

This can also be helpful:
    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: you are right, I did not think ybout the "/" - now it works! :)